# How to delete new-line symbol

Tags: text, copy, newline, text-editor

When I copy a text in PDF file and paste it into Notepad or MS Word, then it looks like this:

```
This is an
example
of the
issue.
```

Original text looks as follows:

`This is an example of the issue`.

Is there any automated way to copy this text as a single line, without new lines?

Answer (score 0):

In Word do cmd+f. then : put `^11`in "find what" and  (space) in "replace".
hit enter.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this approach, but only 2-3 lines have moved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in MS Word: replace `^p` with   (space).